# Responsive slider goes beyond of the wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with responsive slider inside wrapper. When I resize the browser window **vertically** (horizontally adjusts to the width of the wrapper), the wrapper is changing its dimensions and the slider goes beyond it. I tried to solve it in many ways but I can not find a good solution.

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #161616;
}

#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.logo{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 94px;
    margin-top: -26px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-image: url('images/logo.png');
    background-image: no-repeat;
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

.nav ul li a {
    color: #161616;
    /*font-family: Verdana;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #cccccc;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-left: 23px;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.cycle-slideshow {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 90px 20%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.cycle-prev, .cycle-next {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top: 37%;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #161616;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.cycle-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.cycle-next {
    right: 0;
}

.footer{
    position:fixed;
    padding: 38px 0;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 85px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="logo"></div> 
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="cycle-slideshow">
        <span class="cycle-prev">&#10092;</span>
        <span class="cycle-next">&#10093;</span>
        <img src="images/bg.png" alt="Robak" />
        <img src="images/bg2.png" alt="Robak" />
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer info.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running jQuery cycle plugin?  Do you want the slideshow to resize to avoid vertical scrolling when the window is resized?  What's wrong with allowing page scrolling when the vertical space is reduced.

Edit: Try this...

http://codepen.io/robotslater/pen/YyJNER

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #161616;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 94px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-image: url('images/logo.png');
  background-image: no-repeat;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

.nav ul li a {
  color: #161616;
  /*font-family: Verdana;*/
  
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 23px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cycle-slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 90px;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cycle-prev,
.cycle-next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 37%;
  font-size: 200%;
  color: #161616;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.cycle-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.cycle-next {
  right: 0;
}

.cycle-slideshow > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 30px;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div">
    <span class="cycle-prev">&#10092;</span>
    <span class="cycle-next">&#10093;</span>

    <div style="background-image:url(http://s3.freefoto.com/images/9912/01/9912_01_1095_web.jpg)"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer info.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly - it's jQuery cycle plugin. Of course, I would like to avoid vertical scrolling when the window is resized. When I reduce the size of the browser window vertically, I would like to do it in the same way as slider matched in in the horizontally. But I can not find any solution and when I reduce the window vertically, slider goes beyond the wrapper.

Comment: There is not the same type of support for vertical resizing as horizontal resizing.  If you absolutely position elements you can use CSS to react to the window height.  Is the provided HTML all the content on the page or is there more content below the slideshow? If so, is it only the slideshow that you want to keep above the fold?

Comment: Yes, under slideshow you can find footer with some text. Footer should be  right there, just under slidershow and wrapper background.. which contains - logo, nav, slider and footer.

Comment: Checked out the changes I posted in my first comment.  Hopefully it will get you moving in the right direction.